# Copy a Class to a Div with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have looked and I still can not figure out how to copy a `<p>` class named "booking-item-header-price" to the `<div>` named "myDiv" (basically cloning the `<p>` to the `<div`> with JavaScript. It might be important to note that the contents of the `<p>` class changes based on the price of the item. I have tried some things on JSFiddle but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<p class="booking-item-header-price">
   <small>Price</small>
   <span class=" onsale">$70.00</span>
   <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
   <span class="text-lg">$56.00</span>/day                            
</p>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: So the posted code is what you start with, could you please post the code that you want to end up with in the DOM? And show the attempts you've made, we might be able to point out any mistakes or flaws in your implementation in order that you learn something from the supplied answers.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, <p> including children (but keep in mind that the children values may change...not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to move the element: call [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) on the parent element you want to add the element to (`#myDiv`) with a reference to the element you want to move, your `<p>` element.

```
var parent = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
var child = document.querySelector(".booking-item-header-price");
parent.appendChild( child );
```

If you want to copy the element: use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on the child element to make a copy before appending. Pass in `true` for a deep copy,

```
var parent = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
var child = document.querySelector(".booking-item-header-price");
parent.appendChild( child.cloneNode(true) );
```

Note in the copying version you will lose any event listeners you might have applied like through `addEventListener()`

Demo

```js
var parent = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
var child = document.querySelector(".booking-item-header-price");
parent.appendChild( child.cloneNode(true) );
```

```css
#myDiv {
  padding:30px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<p class="booking-item-header-price">
   <small>Price</small>
   <span class=" onsale">$70.00</span>
   <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
   <span class="text-lg">$56.00</span>/day                            
</p>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you nailed it. Appreciate your help. Would +1 ya but I am not able to due to rank. Thanks, marking as done.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function copy(){
  document.querySelector('#myDiv').innerHTML =
    document.querySelector('.booking-item-header-price').innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<p class="booking-item-header-price">
   <small>Price</small>
   <span class=" onsale">$70.00</span>
   <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
   <span class="text-lg">$56.00</span>/day                            
</p>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="copy()">
Copy to #myDiv
</button>
```

This way we get the innerHTML (all the content including html tags) inside the `.booking-item-header-price`p and assign it to the innerHTML of the `#myDiv` div.

Comment: Would be nice to be some type of explanation instead of just code.

Comment: @CharlieFish Yes, was writing it.

Comment: The above code snippet is good except I do not need a button to copy it to the div. It just does it automatically

Comment: Could you show how to do it automatically without the button?

Comment: Just by placing it outside the function I think you will be fine.

Comment: This only copys the contents of the `<p>` element into `#myDiv`, it does not move or copy the element into `#myDiv`.  And setting `innerHTML` can be inefficient as the HTML has to be re-parsed, either moving the element with an `appendChild` call or copying with [`cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) then `appendChild()` would be better IMO

Comment: Good point, but I almost never modify DOM with pure JS; would appreciate if you answer this question with the efficient way.

Comment: Is there a way to just flat out move <p> and the contents of <p> into the <div>  then. I could live with that if it is easier